# Improve jQuery to reduce repetition

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jQuery to Ajax in an xml feed that looks like this:

```
status>
<script id="tinyhippos-injected"/>
<serverinfo>
<hostname>harvey</hostname>
<external>
http://stats.pingdom.com/3tltrr03waho/1435422/history
</external>
</serverinfo>
<host>
<status>OK</status>
</host>
<service>
<http>OK</http>
<ftp>OK</ftp>
<mysql>OK</mysql>
<pop>OK</pop>
<imap>OK</imap>
<smtp>OK</smtp>
<load>OK</load>
</service>
</status>
```

And using this jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {     
    $.ajax({          
        type:  'GET',
        url:   'https://status.clook.net/xml/status/harvey.xml',
        dataType: 'xml',              
        success: function(xml){
           var http = $(xml).find('http').text();
           var ftp = $(xml).find('ftp').text();
           var mysql = $(xml).find('mysql').text();
           var load = $(xml).find('load').text();

          if(http == 'OK') {
            $(".http img").attr("src","http://placehold.it/40/00cc33/ffffff");
          }
          else if(http == 'WARNING') {
            $(".http img").attr("src","http://placehold.it/40/ff6600/000000");
          }
          else if(http == 'CRITICAL') {
            $(".http img").attr("src","http://placehold.it/40/ff0000/000000");
          }

          if(ftp == 'OK') {
            $(".ftp img").attr("src","http://placehold.it/40/00cc33/ffffff");
          }
          else if(ftp == 'WARNING') {
            $(".ftp img").attr("src","http://placehold.it/40/ff6600/000000");
          }
          else if(ftp == 'CRITICAL') {
            $(".ftp img").attr("src","http://placehold.it/40/ff0000/000000");
          }

          if(mysql == 'OK') {
            $(".mysql img").attr("src","http://placehold.it/40/00cc33/ffffff");
          }
          else if(mysql == 'WARNING') {
            $(".mysql img").attr("src","http://placehold.it/40/ff6600/000000");
          }
          else if(mysql == 'CRITICAL') {
            $(".mysql img").attr("src","http://placehold.it/40/ff0000/000000");
          }

          if(load == 'OK') {
            $(".load img").attr("src","http://placehold.it/40/00cc33/ffffff");
          }
          else if(load == 'WARNING') {
            $(".load img").attr("src","http://placehold.it/40/ff6600/000000");
          }
          else if(load == 'CRITICAL') {
            $(".load img").attr("src","http://placehold.it/40/ff0000/000000");
          }

        }
    });
});
```

To swap the image `src` in this HTML

```
<div class="container">
<h3>Server Status Widget</h3>
  <h4>Hosting Server</h4>

<p><strong>HTTP: </strong><span class="http"><img src="http://placehold.it/40" alt="" /></span></p>

<p><strong>FTP: </strong><span class="ftp"><img src="http://placehold.it/40" alt="" /></span></p>

<p><strong>MySQL: </strong><span class="mysql"><img src="http://placehold.it/40" alt="" /></span></p>

<p><strong>Load: </strong><span class="load"><img src="http://placehold.it/40" alt="" /></span></p>

</div>
```

This is all working great, but I am not that experienced with jQuery and I am sure that code can be improved and made less repetitive. My question would be can I reduce the number of `if` / `else if` statements so I don't need to run through each variable?

Thanks for any help

Mike

Comment: This question could be suitable for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help), as long as (a) your code works as intended, (b) your code is real code, rather than example code, and (c) your code is included in the body of the question. If you wish for a peer review to improve all aspects of your code, please post it on Code Review.

Comment: Are there only three statuses? `OK`, Warning and critical?

Comment: You could use `switch/case` statements. http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp

Comment: There are 4 statuses - `OK`, `WARNING`, `CRITICAL` and `UNKNOWN` - I was going to use the `src` in the HTML for unknown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>Assuming there are only three status messages:
`OK`, `WARNING` and `CRITICAL`.</strike>. The `UNKNOWN` status with it's image URL can also be added in the images object.

The images URL can be stored in an object with the status message as key and the URL as value. Then the key can be used dynamically.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Define images object here
    var images = {
        OK: 'http://placehold.it/40/00cc33/ffffff',
        WARNING: 'http://placehold.it/40/ff6600/000000',
        CRITICAL: 'http://placehold.it/40/ff0000/000000'
    };

    ....
        success: function (xml) {
            var http = $(xml).find('http').text(),
                ftp = $(xml).find('ftp').text(),
                mysql = $(xml).find('mysql').text(),
                load = $(xml).find('load').text();

            // Use the status message to get the image URL from object.
            $('.http img').attr('src', images[http]);
            $('.ftp img').attr('src', images[ftp]);
            $('.mysql img').attr('src', images[mysql]);
            $('.load img').attr('src', images[load]);
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up with, adding changing alt for the images:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var images = {
        OK: 'http://placehold.it/40/00cc33/ffffff',
        WARNING: 'http://placehold.it/40/ff6600/000000',
        CRITICAL: 'http://placehold.it/40/ff0000/000000',
        UNKNOWN: 'http://placehold.it/40'
    };

    $.ajax({          
        type:  'GET',
        url:   'https://status.clook.net/xml/status/harvey.xml',
        dataType: 'xml',              
        success: function(xml){
           var http = $(xml).find('http').text();
           var ftp = $(xml).find('ftp').text();
           var mysql = $(xml).find('mysql').text();
           var load = $(xml).find('load').text();

          $('.http img').attr({
            src: images[http],
            alt: "HTTP Status "+ http +""
          });

          $('.ftp img').attr({
            src: images[ftp],
            alt: "FTP Status "+ ftp +""
          });

          $('.mysql img').attr({
            src: images[mysql],
            alt: "MySQL Status "+ mysql +""
          });

          $('.load img').attr({
            src: images[load],
            alt: "Load Status "+ load +""
          });

        }
    });
});
```